# проблема при реверсировании строки

Tags: javascript

у меня задача реверсировать строку без метода reverse, я не могу понять где у меня тут ошибка, я попытаюсь объяснить логику моего кода: в цикле я методом pop забираю его с str и методом join перемещаю в reversedStr, но что-то не получается

```js
function reverse(str) {
  let reversedStr = []

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    reversedStr.push(str.split('').pop())
  }
  return reversedStr.join('')
}

console.log(reverse(''))
console.log(reverse('abcdef'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А зачем так сложно? Если достаточно пробегаться с конца строки до начала, брать символы и их конкатенировать.

```js
function reverse(str) {
    let reversedStr = '';

    for (let i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        reversedStr += str[i];
    }
    
    return reversedStr;
}

console.log(reverse(''));
console.log(reverse('abcdef'));
```

---

```js
function reverse(str) {
    let reversedStr = '';  
    let strLength = str.length;
    
    str.split('').forEach((char, index) => {
        reversedStr += str[strLength - index - 1];
    });
    
    return reversedStr;
}

console.log(reverse(''));
console.log(reverse('abcdef'));
```

---

В новом исправленном вами вопросе - ответ будет таков:

```js
function reverse(str) {
  let reversedStr = []
  let strSplitted = str.split('');
  
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {    
      reversedStr.push(strSplitted.pop())
  }
  
  return reversedStr.join('')
}

console.log(reverse(''))
console.log(reverse('abcdef'))
```

Comment: я пока только учусь. и часто делаю все слишком сложно, и да спасибо за решение

Comment: @Mageeka в итоге вы хотите все методы (pop, split, push) использовать? Или всё же как попроще?))

Comment: ну мне хотелось бы знать где именно в моем коде ошибка

Comment: @Mageeka на самом деле у вас очень много ошибок, потому что сути всех функций и пр. вы ещё не понимаете)) Например на каждой итерации вы всегда оперируете одной и той же строкой `abcdef`, ни сколько её не уменьшая после каждой итерации цикла..Здесь `reversedStr.split('').push` вы просто заносите данные в какой-то массив, где никак вообще не объявлен и этот пуш уходит просто в пустоту. А `reversedStr` у вас вообще строка и поэтому после первой итерации вы разбиваете не массив символов и хотите туда занести ещё один, хотя это строка..в общем, мне кажется вы и сами не понимаете что вы написали)))

Comment: я немного подправил код, но я не понял как надо уменьшать str

Comment: @Mageeka добавил последний вариант в ответ. Я добавил переменную массив `let strSplitted = str.split('');` и уже от него делаю `.pop()` на каждой итерации. В таком случае всё сработает